# Zoom in on a point with touchpad(using scale and translate and rotate in opengl or metalkit with Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, math, opengl, metalkit

I just create an app like osx preview app. I use opengl or metalkit to render image. I can make zoom with a center point (0,0) by some matrix, but I can not make zoom with point between two fingers with touchpad like preview app, because I do not know how to create my model matrix.

I just ask my problem on apple develop forum, and I find demo on github, but no one can help me.

```
- (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSPoint eventLocation = [event locationInWindow];
    NSPoint center = [self.view convertPoint:eventLocation fromView:nil];
    NSPoint openglCenter = CGPointMake(center.x / ([[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] frame].size.width / 2.0) - 1.0, center.y / ([[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] frame].size.height / 2.0) - 1.0);
    NSRect frame = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] frame];

    if ([event magnification] > 0)
    {
        if ([self zoomValue] <= 2.0)
        {
            [self setZoomValue:[self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
            if(self.zoomValue > 2.0) {
                return;
            }
            self.slider.floatValue = [self zoomValue];

            self.panMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, self.swipX / (frame.size.width / 2.0), -self.swipY / (frame.size.height / 2.0), 1);
            self.scaleMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(self.baseScaleMatrix, self.zoomValue, self.zoomValue, 1);
            GLKMatrix4 model = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self.panMatrix, self.scaleMatrix);
            [self.testView makeChangeWithMat:model];
        } else {
            [self setZoomValue:2.0];
            self.slider.floatValue = [self zoomValue];

            self.panMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, self.swipX / (frame.size.width / 2.0), -self.swipY / (frame.size.height / 2.0), 1);
            self.scaleMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(self.baseScaleMatrix, self.zoomValue, self.zoomValue, 1);
            GLKMatrix4 model = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self.panMatrix, self.scaleMatrix);
            [self.testView makeChangeWithMat:model];
        }
    }
    else if ([event magnification] < 0)
    {
        if ([self zoomValue] + [event magnification] >= 1.0)
        {
            [self setZoomValue:[self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
            self.slider.floatValue = [self zoomValue];

            self.panMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, self.swipX / (frame.size.width / 2.0), -self.swipY / (frame.size.height / 2.0), 1);
            self.scaleMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(self.baseScaleMatrix, self.zoomValue, self.zoomValue, 1);
            GLKMatrix4 model = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self.panMatrix, self.scaleMatrix);
            [self.testView makeChangeWithMat:model];
        }
        else
        {
            [self setZoomValue:1.0];
            if(self.zoomValue < 1.0) {
                return;
            }
            self.slider.floatValue = [self zoomValue];

            self.panMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, self.swipX / (frame.size.width / 2.0), -self.swipY / (frame.size.height / 2.0), 1);
            self.scaleMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(self.baseScaleMatrix, self.zoomValue, self.zoomValue, 1);
            GLKMatrix4 model = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self.panMatrix, self.scaleMatrix);
            [self.testView makeChangeWithMat:model];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To zoom around an arbitrary point you need to:

1. Translate by (center - point), thus changing the origin for step 2
2. Scale by the necessary amount
3. Translate back by -(center - point), thus returning the origin back to (0,0)

You are completely missing one of the translations.  You need something like:

```
NSPoint eventLocation = [event locationInWindow];
NSPoint center = [self.view convertPoint:eventLocation fromView:nil];

double transX = 1.0 - center.x / (frame.size.width / 2.0);
double transY = 1.0 - center.y / (frame.size.height / 2.0);
GLKMatrix4 trans = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, transX, transY, 0);
GLKMatrix4 transBack = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, -transX, -transY, 0);
GLKMatrix4 scaleMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(GLKMatrix4Identity, self.zoomValue, self.zoomValue, 1);
GLKMatrix4 model = GLKMatrix4Multiply( transBack, GLKMatrix4Multiply( GLKMatrix4Multiply( scaleMatrix, trans ), _baseScaleMatrix ) );
```

EDIT: also you can't mix in your projection matrix (_baseScaleMatrix) into your model matrix, projection must be applied first, then the model matrix.

Comment: Thanks,but it not work...,I am tortured by this for two weeks.I ask this question twice, but no one helps me except you.

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't let me give you any specific advice.  Looks like you need to debug on your end and come up with questions that can actually be properly answered

Comment: because I want to zoom in the mouse position, so I change the (double transX = 1.0 - self.swipX / (frame.size.width / 2.0);) to (double transX = (mouse.x - self.swipX) / (frame.size.width / 2.0);), the swip point is just the center of the picture, but I only see that my picture evasive.

Comment: It's my easy demo of my project, https://github.com/arrosev/ImageViewDemo.

Comment: @ZCdream I've updated my answer.  Don't concatenate your aspect ratio correction matrix (_baseScaleMatrix, which is actually the projection matrix) with the scale matrix

Comment: Thank you,Vsevolod. Although it still has a long way to go, it solves the basic problem.

Comment: I just find that there are some deviations when I zoom, is the problem of my mouse icon, or the precision?